# Flask print urls visited

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a function that prints the name of every url visited.

I made a wrapper that can be called like the following:

```
@url_print
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The code for url print is here:

```
def url_print(func, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Url '%s' was visited" % func.__name__)
    return(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've sent is not related to these lines, send your code completely, but more generally if you want to print a function's name in python, you can use `__name__` :

```
def function1(input):
   return input**2

print(function1.__name__)
```

this will print :

```
function1
```

Comment: Even with this fix, the code doesn't work. While it prints the function, whenever I visit the url, it doesn't print. It only prints when I init the app.

Comment: @trigangle can you please tell me where do you call `url_print` method?

Comment: I call the function using the @ symbol write before the view function.